# Ansible: Unable to store command in variable and use it in different host

Tags: ansible

I am trying to set up a `kubernetes` cluster using `kubeadm`

I want to fetch the join command (done on the `master` node) and run it on worker node.

The following approach does not work:

```
- name: kubernetes.yml --> Get the join command
  shell: kubeadm token create --print-join-command
  register: rv_join_command
  when: inventory_hostname in (groups['masters'] | last)
  become: yes


- name: kubernetes.yml --> Store the join command
  set_fact:
    join_command: "{{ rv_join_command.stdout }}"
  run_once: true
  when: inventory_hostname in (groups['masters'] | last)


- name: DEBUG kubernetes.yml --> Print the join command
  debug:
    var: rv_join_command.stdout
  when: inventory_hostname in (groups['masters'] | last)


- name: kubernetes.yml --> Run the join command on kubernetes nodes
  shell: "{{ join_command }}"
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['nodes']
```

as it fails with:

> 'join_command' is undefined

But the approach below also fails:

```
- name: kubernetes.yml --> Run the join command on kubernetes nodes
  shell: "{{ rv_join_command.stdout }}"
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['nodes']
  become: yes
```

> The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you used "-vvv" option to Ansible Playbook and verified that "join_command" variable is indeed set, and as per your expectations?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your actual playbook, but I suspect the `run_once: true` is tripping you up. `set_fact` sets a fact on the current host; if there are multiple hosts in your play, this fact will only be available on one of them.

Comment: I removed `run_once` but I get the same results;

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in larsks' comment above, you are storing the `join_command` var only for a single host (i.e. `groups['masters'] | last`) and it is only available there.

Meanwhile, it is possible to access vars from other hosts from anywhere.

You basically have two options:

1. Modify the `set_fact` to store the var on each node from the result on your master
2. Modify the `join_command` to use the stored var on master on every node

**Option 1**

```yaml
- name: kubernetes.yml --> Store the join command
  set_fact:
    join_command: "{{ hostvars[groups['masters'] | last].rv_join_command.stdout }}"
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['nodes']
# Now you can use join_command on each node
```

**Option 2**

```yaml
# Leave set_fact as it was and then...
- name: kubernetes.yml --> Run the join command on kubernetes nodes
  shell: "{{ hostvars[groups['masters'] | last].join_command }}"
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['nodes']
```